# Should there be a "by" before this -ing word?

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

> The campers have spent many a day warming their bodies by...

Should I write it as,

> The campers have spent many a day **by** warming their bodies by

Edit:
Based on the comments below, I have come to an understanding that the first one is good enough to convey the meaning I intended i.e., the campers were able to survive in the camp for many days because they could warm their bodies by being around fire.

> as you gained eminence fighting many battles

In this situation, my understanding is that there needs to be a "by" before "fighting" because the eminence is attained by fighting battles. Am I correct? Or, is it that the meaning is conveyed even without the "by?"

Comment: Neither version is incorrect, but the first version is better; just one "by" at the end of the sentence.  I assume you will finish it with what they were warming their bodies by in place of the dots (such as "warming their bodies by *the fire*"), then it's perfect!

Comment: In general, using the same word repeatedly close together in a sentence should be avoided.  So you could rewrite this as "The campers have spent many a day warming their bodies by lying near the fire".  You can also skip "by" entirely - "The campers have spent many a day warming their bodies around the fire".

Comment: Please edit to tell us more about what concerns you about the phrase. I assume that you noticed that "warming" uses "by" but "spent" didn't, but I might be wrong. Questions that ask "is this wrong" are off-topic unless a clear area of concern is communicated.

Comment: If there's any omitted preposition there, it's, "*The campers have spent many a day **in** warming their bodies...*". "By" indicates *how* something was achieved or completed. The campers didn't achieve or complete "spending many a day...", but the solder did achieve gaining eminence **by** fighting many battles, so "by" is correct in the second one

Answer (score 1):

1

> The campers have spent many a day warming their bodies by [phrase].

2

> The campers have spent many a day **by** warming their bodies by [phrase].

In (1), the focus is the task *warming their bodies*. The campers may have got into a cold situation, an undesirable one.

In (2), there is no such situation.  The campers may have scheduled several days at the campsite to relax.  They decided to utilise some of the days warming their bodies.

(1) could be a more likely scenario you want to describe.

Comment: Yes, the first one fits my need. "as you gained eminence fighting many battles"  In this situation, my understanding is that there needs to be a "by" before "fighting" because the eminence is attained by fighting battles. Am I correct?

Comment: Or is it that the meaning is conveyed even without the "by"